# Creating unique index seems to fail, but is created anyway?

Tags: postgresql, indexing, unique-index

Am creating a unique (multi-column) index, but it fails, because there non-unique rows in the table already. However, the index seems to be created anyway...

This is the SQL I'm using:

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX CONCURRENTLY IF NOT EXISTS company_by_code ON public.company USING BTREE("owner","org","code")
```

Which results in the following response from Postgresql:

```
ERROR:  could not create unique index "company_by_code"
DETAIL:  Key (owner, org, code)=(ABC, DEF, XYZ) is duplicated.
SQL state: 23505
```

However, even though the CREATE statement seemed to error out, the INDEX seems to be created anyway.

Is that to be expected?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is [documented in the manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createindex.html#SQL-CREATEINDEX-CONCURRENTLY)

> If a problem arises while scanning the table, such as a deadlock or a uniqueness violation in a unique index, the CREATE INDEX command will fail but leave behind an “invalid” index. This index will be ignored for querying purposes because it might be incomplete; however it will still consume update overhead. The psql `\d` command will report such an index as INVALID

If you don't want that behaviour, don't use `CONCURRENTLY`

Comment: Thank you very much!. Did look around in the docs, but didn't tie this to also using CONCURRENTLY, so didn't read that in detail

Comment: @Paul: the section from where I quoted has the title "Building Indexes Concurrently"

Comment: yup, I know, should've paid more attention. Had this behavior been mentioned under UNIQUE, I probably would've found it. As I said, didn't think this behavior could be because of using CONCURRENTLY, so didn't look at that